# Java error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

Tags: java, eclipse

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=4816, tid=4100
>   fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
>
> JRE version:  (7.0_67-b01) (build )
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
>   Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x011bd400):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=4100, stack(0x01290000,0x012e0000)]
>
> Stack: [0x01290000,0x012e0000],  sp=0x012df98c,  free space=318k
>   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x190494]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x18a116]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x35d7a]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x35e06]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x4465d]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x4490e]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x92f8a]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x9333b]
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x13fa31]

I wrote a piece of code to read and search a XML file. The code itself did not give me any error, but when I ran it, the code got terminated. This is the message I got from C:\Users\ximinmi\workspace\OldImageReveal. OldImageReveal is the package I am working on. Below is the code. I am just testing it with a W3C page. Thanks.

```
package com.oldimagereveal;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Search_XML{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");

            // Create XPathFactory object
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            String address = getAddress(doc, xpath, 4);
            System.out.println("Image Address is: " + address);

            List<String> addresses = getAddresses(doc, xpath, 30);
            System.out.println("All addresses are" + Arrays.toString(addresses.toArray()));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private static List<String> getAddresses(Document doc, XPath xpath, int age) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            XPathExpression expr =
                xpath.compile("/Records/Record[Address>" + getAddress(doc, xpath, 4) + "]/name/text()");
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
                list.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }


    private static String getAddress(Document doc, XPath xpath, int id) {
        String name = null;
        try {
            XPathExpression expr =
                xpath.compile("/Records/Record[@id='" + id + "']/name/text()");
            name = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't actually look at the code in your local directory...

Comment: I can; they're using Windows. Arrrrrrr ye scurvy dogs, prepare to be boarded.

Comment: I do not think it is a code problem, to be honest. I found this page: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/references/intel-4-series-chipsets/ Basically it says I need either a new computer or at least a new CPU. I am adding my code in my post now.

Comment: @DaveNewton careful you don't get infected when you go in. Otherwise before you know it you'll be designing Christmas cards in PowerPoint.

Comment: How are you running this program? Do you define any JVM flags? Can you try with most recent Java version?

Comment: That is a *very* different error than what you are seeing.

Comment: @Banthar: yes I am. I actually think that is the problem. Maybe should use a lower version. Here is a link about this error: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/references/intel-4-series-chipsets/

Comment: @Q-ximi That error doesn't seem actually related. In your case Java crashes in jvm.dll. Crash from that link happens inside ig4dev32.dll. ig4dev32.dll is part of Intel graphic drivers. I have no idea why that would be loaded in XML parser.

Comment: @Banther: I am new to Java, now totally lost as to where to get started to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I faced the same problem and I fix it by changing the jdk.

In my case the problema occurs when I try to run the app with ecplise, so I changed the jdk version and that is! I was using the jdk 1.8.0_181 and I change it for 1.8.0_05.

Comment: I had 1.8.0_181 in my PATH but my project was using 1.8.0_66, and DCEVM wouldn't install on _66 (it said it did, but it also couldn't get the ver, which is this error), so I installed it on _181 (no errors), set the project to use _181, and everything worked. Granted, I'm using an updated version of HotSwapAgent and IntelliJ, but it's the same error/solution.